# What's the point in omitting spaces around Ruby's exponent operator?

Tags: ruby

I'm just curious about what the grounds are for omitting spaces around Ruby's exponent operator. [Community-based Ruby coding style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#source-code-layout) says one should use spaces around operators except the exponent operator (`**`), i.e.:

```
# bad
e = M * c ** 2

# good
e = M * c**2
```

I failed to find any info about the question at all.

Comment: Except that it's far easier to distinguish (from a single `*`) AND emphasizes the higher precedence of `**` operator?

Comment: Here's the GitHub issue: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide/issues/44

Comment: Thank you, guys, that's definitely the answer to the question.

Comment: I actually disagree with it. Uniformity of coding style to me is more important than *distinguishability*. This exception is not valid enough.

Comment: @konsolebox, it's up to you to decide whether to use spaces around the exponent operator or not. Guidelines are recommendations rather than rules.

Comment: @dskecse Yes of course. Mainly I'm just wanting to give my own preference or opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Probably to mirror the hand-written way of expressing that the exponent operator has a high precedence to the term it's associated with:

Written:

- M x c<sup>2</sup>

Code:

- `M * c**2`

Comment: Well, thanks, but we've already come to a conclusion that it's because it's far easier to distinguish from a single `*` and the latter form looks like priority notion.

Comment: Oh, I didn't expand the comments. Posted an answer because there weren't any.